# Rails 3: How to stop logger from logging /healthcheck requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have a rails app on 2 servers and it uses a load balancer. The load balancer makes requests to /healthcheck every few seconds to make sure that the servers are still available. However, this is filling up my production logs. Is there a way to filter out requests to healthcheck#healthcheck ?

Answer (score -2):

quiet_assets removes calls to your assets in development. I'm sure you could probably do something similar in production for healthchecks.

https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets/blob/master/lib/quiet_assets.rb